# Erewhon fonts and mathfrak symbols

Tags: fonts, luatex, math-fonts

I'm trying to get the [`erewhon`](https://ctan.org/pkg/erewhon) font to work, but I miss some specific `mathfrak` fonts when using it. For example, `\mathfrak{h}` only displays a regular h instead, while `\mathfrak{g}` works. The example below is how I have my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[proportional,scaled=1.064]{erewhon}
\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\(\mathfrak{g}\) \(\mathfrak{h}\)

\end{document}
```

Where the options passed to both `erewhon` and `nextxmath` are just as in the snippet [here](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/erewhon/).

I'm using LuaTeX to have all fonts compiled as Erewhon, since PDFTeX apparently has problems with that. All the AMS packages (`amsfonts`, `amsmath` and `amssymb`) actually do nothing in this case. So, what am I missing?

Comment: you almost certainly don't want `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex (as that specifies legacy 8 bit encodings disabling all the unicode support) (it doesn't affect math, as used in this example)

Comment: The bug has been fixed and the corrected version has hit the TeX Live repositories, see updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX is using the OpenType `Erewhon-Math.otf` font. The recommended way to load this font is through the package `fourier-otf`, which sets some suitable options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}

\begin{document}

\(\mathfrak{g}\) \(\mathfrak{h}\)

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have never not used PDFLaTeX before, only now when I've tried different fonts, so I really don't know much about the other engines. Is it possible to do something like that with PDFLaTeX?

Comment: @kindaichi Indeed to use OTF or TTF fonts (like the font `Erewhon-Math.otf` that is used in this answer) you need LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, it is not possible to load such fonts with pdfLaTeX. There are a lot of fonts available for pdfLaTeX through packages such as `newtx`, but these fonts have been converted to the specific format that pdfLaTeX understands, which is a very complicated process. Sometimes such fonts for pdfLaTeX are incomplete (i.e., are missing some letters/symbols in some font variants like Fraktur) and there is not much that you can do about that.

Answer (score 9):

#### Updated answer

The bug in the fonts has been fixed with version 1.121.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[proportional,scaled=1.064]{erewhon}
\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\(\mathfrak{g}+\mathfrak{h}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Original answer

It's a bug in the font `zutmia`, which LaTeX is supposed to take Fraktur math letters from.

This is the relevant part from the font table

[image]

where you see that the “h” is completely out of place.

How to fix the issue? You can take the Fraktur letter from a different font. Here's how to use the AMS ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[proportional,scaled=1.064]{erewhon}
\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

\(\mathfrak{g}+\mathfrak{h}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I filed a bug report to the font maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[proportional,scaled=1.064]{erewhon}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % For font loading
\usepackage{unicode-math} % For math font setup
\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]
\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathfrak}]{latinmodern-math.otf} % Fallback fraktur font
\usepackage{amsmath} % For math environments and commands

\begin{document}

$\mathfrak{g}$ $\mathfrak{h}$

\end{document}
```

[image]